# How to play music in my app to a bluetooth enabled speaker through a2dp?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I want to play the audio which is located in my app to a bluetooth enabled speaker device. How can it be done using the core bluetooth library of ios. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: CoreBluetooth, Apple's framework for Bluetooth Low-Energy isn't suitable for Audio.

Comment: How can it be done using a2dp. Music player of iphone can play the song in bluetooth speaker when it is connected to it.

Comment: You use the AVAudioSession class to enumerate the available outputs and select one